# Logic for limits

Tags: limits

How $1^\infty$ is an indeterminate form?

Anything raised to the power of 1 is 1:p

I know that infinity is just a symbol to denote an unknown thing but still confused.

Comment: I suppose it means (something $\to$ 1)^(something $\to \infty$)? Like $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n)^n$?

Comment: No it is not when you have an inner function that depends on the limit variable. Take $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1 + \frac 1n\right)^n = e$

Comment: *"How is $\infty\cdot 0$ an indeterminate form? 
Anything multiplied by $0$ is $0$ :p"*

Comment: Or somewhat more obviously: $x^{1 / \ln x} = (e^{\ln x})^{1 / \ln x} = e^1 = e$ for all $x > 1$ so $\lim_{x\to 1^+} x^{1 / ln x} = e$; but $x \to 1$ and $\frac{1}{\ln x} \to \infty$.

Comment: Yes I understood it very well now. Thankyou all☺

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Infinity is not a real number, so "anything raised to the power of 1" isn't applicable (which, by the way, is completely backwards... I think you mean "1 raised to any power" where "any" means "any real number.").

---

Now to see that we cannot just blindly assign a value to a limit of this form, notice that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac 1 n\right)^n = e$$

while

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac 1 n\right)^n = \frac 1 e$$

and

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac 1 n\right)^{n^2} = \infty$$

and

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac 1 {n^2}\right)^n = 1.$$

As you can see, in each case the actual limit depends on how quickly the base tends to $1$ and how quickly the exponent tends towards infinity.

In some sense: if the base tends to $1$ quickly enough, the limit is $1$; if the exponent blows up too rapidly, the limit is infinite.

Comment: I see that there is someone reflexively downvoting all answers. While I can commiserate with the impulses that lead to this behavior, I feel it's worth pointing out that this is not a do-my-homework question, but is based on a very common misunderstanding for this level of student. And the downvoter would likely be familiar with that if they teach a calc 2 class.

Comment: I like your answer (and I agree with your comment).

Answer (score 4):

If $a>0$ then $a^b=e^{b\ln(a)}$. So we may say (informally) that
$$1^{\infty}=\exp(\infty\cdot\ln(1))=\exp(\infty\cdot 0)$$
which is indeterminate because of the product $\infty\cdot 0$.

As an explicit example, note that for $a>0$ the following limit, which is an indeterminate form $1^{\infty}$, depends on the value of $a$:
$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to +\infty }\left(1+\frac{1}{n^a}\right)^{n}&=
\lim_{n\to +\infty }\exp\left(n\ln(1+1/n^a)\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to +\infty }\exp\left(1/n^{a-1}\right)=\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if $a>1$,}\\
e&\text{if $a=1$,}\\
+\infty&\text{if $0<a<1$.}
\end{cases}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

Consider the sequence:
$$a_n = (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$$

Now as $n \rightarrow \infty$, the inside of the expression goes to $1$ and the exponent goes to $\infty$. However, the limit of this sequence is $e$.

Comment: Simple and correct!

Answer (score 2):

Note that for

- $f(x)\to 1$
- $g(x)\to \infty$

$$f(x)^{g(x)}=e^{g(x)\log(f(x))}$$

and

$$g(x)\log(f(x))=\infty\cdot 0$$

which is indeterminate.